# Node.js Promise loop resolves not every object

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, promise, resolve

I'm trying to parse a XML file, build a object of that infos and push the results to an array. This runs on a node js server so I use promises to do this synchron. In the `parseImportantInfos` method all parsed objects are printed correct to the console, but after I resolve this objects to the `getLocations` methode and console.log again only the first situationrecord of one situation will be resolved.

The XML looks like:

```
...
<situation>
 <situationrecord version="123">...</situationrecord>
 <situationrecord version="123">...</situationrecord>
</situation>
<situation>
 <situationrecord version="456">...</situationrecord>
 <situationrecord version="456">...</situationrecord>
</situation>
...
<!-- sometimes there is only one situationrecord -->
<situation>
 <situationrecord version="789">...</situationrecord>
</situation>
```

This is the part of my code where the parsed objects get "lost".

```
let getLocations = function(xmlArr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (var x in xmlArr) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(xmlArr[x]);
      var promiseList = [];
      $('situation').each(function() {
        var newPromise = parseImportantInfos($, this)
          .then(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj); // <---- Here are parsed situations missing, only the first situationrecord of a situation is received
            if (obj != "") {
              constructionsites.push(obj);
            }
          });
        promiseList.push(newPromise);
      });
      Promise.all(promiseList)
        .then(function() {
          resolve(constructionsites);
        });
    }
  });
};

let parseImportantInfos = function($, record) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $(record).find('situationRecord').each(function() {
      var startLocationCode = $(this).find('alertCMethod2SecondaryPointLocation').find('specificLocation').text();
      var endLocationCode = $(this).find('alertCMethod2PrimaryPointLocation').find('specificLocation').text();
      var managementType = $(this).find('roadOrCarriagewayOrLaneManagementType').text();
      if (startLocationCode != '' && endLocationCode != '' && managementType != 'roadClosed') {
        createSituationRecord($, this, startLocationCode, endLocationCode)
          .then(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj); // <----------- This log prints all parsed infos correct
            resolve(obj);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject("There was an error while parsing the xml");
            console.log('err', err.stack);
          });
      } else {
        resolve("");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I already debugged the project but can't figure out why only one part of the object where resolved

Comment: the fact that you have a resolve inside `$(record).find('situationRecord').each(function () {` suggests you don't understand that a promise can only be resolved **once**

Comment: Put your code into http://jshint.com. Solve all the problems that are pointed out to you.

Comment: That was the information I needed. Thanks @JaromandaX I will accept your answer if you post it

Comment: Thanks for the link @Tomalak I will make use of it

Comment: And the next thing you should read is ["What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/18771) and throw out all the lines with `new Promise()`. In your code, there is no need to construct new promises anywhere.